# Where are the profession trainers in TOR?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've been running around Korriban for a while now, and noticed that some of the beasties that I've been force choking to death have "Bioanalysis Required" popping up on their corpse.

I'm aware this is a gathering profession, but I've not seen any indication as to where I can *learn* such a profession.

Where do you have to go to learn a profession in TOR? Is there not a trainer on the starting planets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crew Trainers can be found both with your faction's fleet and on your faction's capitol city, and possibly on other planets as well.

You can have three professions at a time, but only one of them can be a crafting profession.

Each crafting profession has recommended gathering professions for it.  For example, Artificing (to create light saber mods) recommends Archaeology (for crystals) and Treasure Hunting (for gemstones).

Bonus tip: Talk to every trainer before choosing your professions to complete your codex entries for professions.

For the most part, your crew will do the crafting and gathering for you.

Once you have multiple crew mates, it's a good idea to send the ones not with you on crafting or gathering tasks.

Comment: I forgot to mention this before, but some companions have bonuses to specific Professions.  I don't know enough to make a complete list of them at this point, and it is likely beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

No, crew skill trainers are not on start worlds.  You'll encounter them when you leave and go to your faction's Fleet (with or without a companion, thanks Ward), around level 10, or immediately afterward on Coruscant or Dromund Kaas.

They're quite easy to find on the Fleet; on the Republic's Carrick Station they take up the Northwest quadrant of the outer ring and for Imperials it's the Southeast quad.  On Coruscant the trainers are underneath the plaza in front of the Senate building, and on Dromund Kaas they are in the Nexus Room Cantina of Kaas City.

New in 2.0 there are also crew skill trainers on Makeb at Avesta Plantation (Republic) and Gravity Hook Seven's Loading Ring (Empire), as well as on the Makeb Orbital Stations for each faction.

Comment: Rather or not your companion is with you or not this wont change anything. You get your two gathering skills and one crafting, and all of your compaions can do all of them. You then simply select a compaion then select any of the skills you trained in for gathering origionally and send them out... EDIT: wanted to add that this is also the case on the empire fleet as both sides faction fleet station is almost identical outside of visual astetics.

Comment: @Sjoerd It's incredibly easy to get to Fleet without a companion, you can even learn crew skills and pick up and complete the "Learn a craft skill" mission, however there's no way to use the craft skills without a companion. Just go to your starting world's spaceport, jump on a shuttle and you're there. My spare level 3 Imp Agent is on Fleet and has a full set of (unusable) crew skills, even though he's still in the "Prologue" story and has no companion.

Comment: @GAThrawn I thought it wasn't possible as it required a shuttle pass. But I stand corrected. I've removed my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your companion, you can select gathering/crafting professions. (usually it's done at about lvl 10 on your faction's fleet)